# Failure of Observable.filter to prevent invalid value after a valid one

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, rxjs5

I have the following `Rxjs` code

```
  Observable.combineLatest(
        this.form.statusChanges,
        this.form.valueChanges,
        ( status, value ) => ({ status, value }) )
              .filter( ( { status } ) => status === 'VALID' )
              .debounceTime( 500 )
              .subscribe( ( { value } ) => createAddress( this._store, value ) )
```

I observed the following:

1. No value is passed to the store until the values are valid.
2. Once the value is valid, the input of an invalid value passes to the store and after that no other passes.

Why does the filter NOT filter the first invalid value after a valid Object?

### EDIT 1 | SOLVED

#### Place the filter immediately before the subscribe() function as shown below:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    this.form.statusChanges,
    this.form.valueChanges,
    ( status, value ) => ({ status, value }) )
          .debounceTime( 500 )
          .filter( ( { status } ) => status === 'VALID' )
          .subscribe( ( { value } ) => createAddress( this._store, value ) )
```

Comment: Try: `this.form.statusChanges.startWith(this.form.status)` (and similar for `valueChanges` observable). If it doesn't help can you provide a plunker with an example?

Comment: Does not work. I will supply a plunker soon.

Comment: Rather than edit the solution into your question, it would be better if you added it as a [self answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).